# Excel VBA list comparison long processing time

Tags: excel, vba, list

I'm new to stackoverflow so not sure if I can ask questions like this but I'm running a code that is taking a long time to process and I was wondering what I could do to reduce the processing time.

I have a list in column A and comparing it to values in Column B and C.

If the values that exist in column A are not present columns B and C then they come up in column E.

The code looks like this.

```
    Const Col_1 As String = "A"
    Const Col_2 As String = "B"
    Const Col_3 As String = "C"
    Const Col_5 As String = "E"
    Const StartRow As Long = 1
'-------------------------------
  LastRow_1 = Cells(Rows.Count, Col_1).End(xlUp).Row
  LastRow_2 = Cells(Rows.Count, Col_2).End(xlUp).Row
  LastRow_3 = Cells(Rows.Count, Col_3).End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Cells(StartRow, Col_5).Resize(LastRow_1 - StartRow + 1)
    .Value = Evaluate("IF(COUNTIF(" & Col_2 & StartRow & ":" & Col_3 & LastRow_3 & ", " & Col_1 & StartRow & ":" & Col_1 & LastRow_1 & "),""""," & Col_1 & StartRow & ":" & Col_1 & LastRow_1 & ")")
    On Error Resume Next
    .SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Delete xlShiftUp
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If a value does exists in column A but doesn't appear in columns B or C then the code processes quickly.

However, if there are no missing values in column B or C (where all values in column A appear in columns B and C), then ironically the macro takes a long time to execute.

I was wondering what could be the reason for this and what I could do to correct the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: the code takes a very long time especially if there is only one value in column A and if that value exists somewhere in columns B and C.

Comment: It's the deletion of blank cells which causes the delay - if you just want to eliminate blanks then you could just sort that column, so that blanks appear at the end - much less work for Excel. Also, there are 2 versions of Evaluate, one for Application, and one for Worksheet, so that line could be optimised with '.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate...'

Comment: It works like a dream now. Thanks. Btw I don't understand why '.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate...' works so much better?

Comment: See this article on Evaluate:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/